# Pre-populate current value of WTForms field in order to edit it

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have a form inside a modal that I use to edit a review on an item (a perfume). A perfume can have multiple reviews, and the reviews live in an array of nested documents, each one with its own _id.

I'm editing each particular review (in case an user wants to edit their review on the perfume once it's been submitted) by submitting the EditReviewForm to this `edit_review` route:

```
@reviews.route("/review", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def edit_review():
    form = EditReviewForm()
    review_id = request.form.get("review_id")
    perfume_id = request.form.get("perfume_id")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        mongo.db.perfumes.update(
            {"_id": ObjectId(perfume_id), <I edit my review here> })
        return redirect(url_for("perfumes.perfume", perfume_id=perfume_id))
    return redirect(url_for("perfumes.perfume", perfume_id=perfume_id))
```

And this route redirects to my perfume route, which shows the perfume and all the reviews it contains.

This is the `perfume` route:

```
@perfumes.route("/perfume/<perfume_id>", methods=["GET"])
def perfume(perfume_id):
    current_perfume = mongo.db.perfumes.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(perfume_id)})
    add_review_form = AddReviewForm()
    edit_review_form = EditReviewForm()
    cur = mongo.db.perfumes.aggregate(etc)
    edit_review_form.review.data = current_perfume['reviews'][0]['review_content']
    return render_template(
        "pages/perfume.html",
        title="Perfumes",
        cursor=cur,
        perfume=current_perfume,
        add_review_form=add_review_form,
        edit_review_form=edit_review_form
    )
```

***My issue***

To find a way to get the `review _id` in that process and have it in my `perfume` route, so I can pre-populate my EditReviewForm with the current value. Otherwise the form looks empty to the user editing their review.

By hardcoding an index (index [0] in this case):

```
edit_review_form.review.data = current_perfume['reviews'][0]['review_content']
```

I am indeed displaying current values, but of course the same value for all reviews, as the reviews are in a loop in the template, and I need to get the value each review_id has.

Is there a way to do this, before I give up with the idea of allowing users to edit their reviews? :D

Please do let me know if my question is clear or if there's more information needed.

Thanks so much in advance!!

**UPDATE 2:**

Trying to reduce further my current template situation to make it clearer:

The modal with the review is fired from `perfume-reviews.html`, from this button:

```
<div class="card-header">
    <button type="button" class="btn edit-review" data-perfume_id="{{perfume['_id']}}" data-review_id="{{review['_id']}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editReviewPerfumeModal" id="editFormButton">Edit</button>
</div>
```

And that opens the modal where my form with the review is (the field in question is a `textarea` currently displaying a WYSIWYG from CKEditor:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form method=POST action="{{ url_for('reviews.edit_review') }}" id="form-edit-review">
        <div class="form-group" id="reviewContent">
            {{ edit_review_form.review(class="form-control ckeditor", placeholder="Review")}}
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Currently this isn't working:

```
$(document).on("click", "#editFormButton", function (e) {
    var reviewText = $(this)
        .parents(div.card.container)
        .siblings("div#reviewContent")
        .children()
        .text();
    $("input#editReviewContent").val(reviewText);
});
```

and throws a `ReferenceError: div is not defined`.

Where am I failing here? (Perhaps in more than one place?)

**UPDATE 3:**

this is where the button opens the modal, and underneath it's where the review content displays:

```
<div class="card container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card-header col-9">
            <h5>{{review['reviewer'] }} said on {{ review.date_reviewed.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header col-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-2 edit-review float-right ml-2" data-perfume_id="{{perfume['_id']}}" data-review_id="{{review['_id']}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editReviewPerfumeModal" id="editFormButton">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-3 row">
        <div class=" col-10" id="reviewContent">
            <li>{{ review['review_content'] | safe }}</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `populate_obj` method of `Form`, used somewhat like:
`form.populate_obj(perfume.reviews[0])`. Works if the naming of model and form is consistent.

Comment: Thank you @janmpeterka! I do know how to populate the form, if I only could get the review_id to my `perfume` route! :D

Comment: Could you post your HTML code for ```perfume.html```. That would help in better understanding!

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question! I hope I didn't make it too bulky! :)

Comment: I think you can do it through JQuery or pure javascript! Is that are you looking for?

Comment: I'd love to if that's the way. Do you think you could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) as when you open the form, the form will automatically show the review content in there. It will be done by manipulating the dom.

Also, add an id to your edit button, in this example, I have given it an id "editFormButton".

Similarly, add an id to the div in which review content lies so that it is easier to select, I have given it an id "reviewContent"

Similarly, add an id to `edit_review_form.review` like this `edit_review_form.review(id='editReviewContent')`

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#editFormButton", function (e) {
 var reviewText = $(this)
        .parents("div.row")
        .siblings("div.p-3.row")
        .children("div#reviewContent")
        .children()
        .text();
    $("input#editReviewContent").val(reviewText);
});
</script>
```

Don't forget to include jQuery.

Also, you can do it with pure javascript. You can easily search the above equivalents on google. This [article](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/move-from-jquery-to-vanilla-javascript/) is a good start!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help!!
This isn't currently working and I'm getting a `not defined` error in the console.
I just updated (Update 2) my question, perhaps you could see where's the error or errors?
Thanks so much!!

Comment: ```{{ edit_review_form.review(class="form-control ckeditor",placeholder="Review",id='editReviewContent')}}```
 Put an id on form input

Comment: Also remove the id ```reviewContent``` from the ```<div>``` element under which your form input is and put that id  ```reviewContent``` on ```<div>``` element under which your review content lies.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't understand your last sentence and don't know where to give the id "reviewContent". So sorry about that.

Comment: My review content is here, but the id doesn't help:
 ` <div class=" col-10" id="reviewContent"><li>{{ review['review_content'] | safe }}</li>
</div>`

Comment: And the console error is about not finding a div in this line of your script:

`.parents(div.card.container)`

Comment: I just updated my question with the template with the button opening the review edit modal and the review content place. I hope it helps!

Comment: try the update, it is according to the modified html

Comment: Great, I don't get any console errors now, but I don't get the value of the review showing! :D Maybe we are getting really close!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214674/discussion-between-kartikeya-sharma-and-guillermo-brachetta).

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I fixed it! 
The issue was: when I added `id=editReviewContent` in my textarea filed, that was overriding the one dynamically created by CKEditor. I deleted it, since we don't use that anymore in your script and it just works perfect!
Thank you SO MUCH for your time and patience! I'm selecting your answer as the correct one, but if you want to update it so it can help others, please be welcome!!

Comment: You could edit my answer. Like what worked for you and then I will approve it!